# mysql crashing with "mysqld got signal 11"

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I'm running application which reading and writing data with mysql database. I'm having both mysql ndbclustr and master master replication in same database. (bcoz of master master replication tables' engines are innodb, clustering won't replicate data of those tables.)

I'm having 64GB RAM in each MYSQL server and there are 2 servers with same configurations

Issue I'm getting is, when writing to tables after a few minutes of a time I'm getting

```
05:49:16 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;

This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=502
max_threads=600
thread_count=505
connection_count=501
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 369478 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fe8ac0273a0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fea140bae70 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xf7246b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x461)[0x82a6e1]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x7fee30719100]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12NdbOperation23insertKEYINFO_NdbRecordEPKcj+0xda)[0x136d69a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12NdbOperation21buildSignalsNdbRecordEjyPKj+0x5bd)[0x136de1d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN16NdbScanOperation23takeOverScanOpNdbRecordEN12NdbOperation13OperationTypeEP14NdbTransactionPK9NdbRecordPcPKhPKNS0_16OperationOptionsEj+0x1f1)[0x1370651]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13ha_ndbcluster14ndb_update_rowEPKhPhi+0x5e7)[0x12ec577]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_updateP3THDR4ListI4ItemES4_y15enum_duplicatesPyS6_+0x1305)[0xdc5625]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_update23try_single_table_updateEP3THDPb+0x1d6)[0xdc7b16]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_update7executeEP3THD+0x36)[0xdc7e56]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x5d0)[0xd3d680]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x3b5)[0xd43a55]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0xa7a)[0xd4454a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x19f)[0xd45f8f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x288)[0xe055d8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0x142e644]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x7fee30711dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fee2f1cd1cd]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fe8ac02b980): update dash_subscription_total_count set subscription = 38, unsubscription =10, authentication = 2368553
Connection ID (thread ID): 1107
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

**Below contains the outputs related to**

**mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'key_%';**

```
+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Key_blocks_not_flushed | 0      |
| Key_blocks_unused      | 107171 |
| Key_blocks_used        | 3      |
| Key_read_requests      | 6      |
| Key_reads              | 3      |
| Key_write_requests     | 0      |
| Key_writes             | 0      |
+------------------------+--------+
```

**mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime_%';**

```
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| Uptime_since_flush_status | 613    |
```

***http://mysqlcalculator.com/ this site shows the output for memory as 32522 MB.***

**Mysql Configuration**

```
[mysqld]
#ndbcluster                      # run NDB storage engine
open_files_limit =4096
max_connections = 600
event_scheduler = OFF

server-id = 14
log-bin=mysql-bin
expire_logs_days=1
binlog_format=mixed
relay-log=mysql-relay-bin
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_0
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_1
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_2
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_3
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_4
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_5
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_6
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_7
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_8
replicate-do-table=css_cluster_ndb.transaction_log_9

skip-name-resolve=1
symbolic-links=0
wait_timeout=120
interactive_timeout=120
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=32M
thread_cache_size=36
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=15G
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT    #O_DSYNC, O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
key_buffer_size=128M
max_connect_errors = 2000
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=15
slave-skip-errors=1590
slave-skip-errors=1533
table_open_cache =8000
#######################
#######################################
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
log_timestamps = SYSTEM
##############################
auto-increment-increment = 2 # No of replication servers
auto-increment-offset = 5 # First replication server

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

ndbcluster
#bind-address=10.81.133.2
#bind-address=10.80.172.194
ndb-connectstring=10.81.133.5:1186      # IP address for server management node
#ndb-connectstring=10.81.133.5:1186      # IP address for server management node
default_storage_engine=ndbcluster     # Define default Storage Engine used by MySQL
#log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

[mysql_cluster]
#ndb-connectstring=10.81.133.5    # IP address for server management node
ndb-connectstring=10.81.133.5
```

**SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS**

```
| InnoDB |      | 
=====================================
2018-03-12 13:00:06 0x7f4d495c0700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 24 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 422 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 210 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 632
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 3725
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 4814
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 1901, OS waits 128
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 69393, OS waits 5
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 1901.00 RW-shared, 69393.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 2024054201
Purge done for trx's n:o < 2024041077 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 53
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421461956475616, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421461956474704, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421461956473792, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
13166 OS file reads, 6011 OS file writes, 2135 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 1.75 writes/s, 1.12 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 160766, seg size 160768, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 3983951, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
0.37 hash searches/s, 0.21 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 1096750789777
Log flushed up to   1096750789777
Pages flushed up to 1096750789777
Last checkpoint at  1096750789768
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
3508 log i/o's done, 0.83 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 16491479040
Dictionary memory allocated 268388
Buffer pool size   982920
Free buffers       972688
Database pages     10231
Old database pages 3874
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 10192, created 39, written 5341
0.00 reads/s, 0.04 creates/s, 0.92 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 10231, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64836
Database pages     692
Old database pages 275
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 692, created 0, written 403
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.08 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 692, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64759
Database pages     769
Old database pages 303
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 769, created 0, written 415
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 769, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64818
Database pages     710
Old database pages 282
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 710, created 0, written 282
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 710, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64872
Database pages     656
Old database pages 262
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 656, created 0, written 309
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 656, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64836
Database pages     692
Old database pages 273
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 688, created 4, written 534
0.00 reads/s, 0.04 creates/s, 0.67 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 692, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64960
Database pages     568
Old database pages 229
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 568, created 0, written 379
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 568, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       65058
Database pages     470
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 470, created 0, written 267
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 470, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64751
Database pages     777
Old database pages 306
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 777, created 0, written 365
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 777, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 8
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64883
Database pages     645
Old database pages 258
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 645, created 0, written 168
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 645, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 9
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64778
Database pages     750
Old database pages 296
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 750, created 0, written 374
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 750, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 10
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64811
Database pages     717
Old database pages 284
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 717, created 0, written 254
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 717, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 11
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64944
Database pages     583
Old database pages 235
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 583, created 0, written 272
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.17 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 583, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 12
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64783
Database pages     745
Old database pages 295
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 745, created 0, written 471
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 745, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 13
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64694
Database pages     834
Old database pages 327
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 799, created 35, written 570
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 834, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 14
Buffer pool size   65528
Free buffers       64905
Database pages     623
Old database pages 249
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 623, created 0, written 278
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 623, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=988, Main thread ID=139970148284160, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 427, updated 0, deleted 0, read 8
0.50 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: After reducing the max_connections=2000,key_buffer_size=1G and read_buffer_size=8M I'm getting the following error. But this time it came after 3hours of time during my load testing time. I will change the above question so you can understand the error log and other outputs correctly...

Comment: RAM  nnn GB on your Host server, indicate DEDICATED or SHARED w other apps 
current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
E) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
Optional very helpful info, if available includes 
htop   OR  top for most active apps
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x       for a linux/unix for IOPS of hardware  extended status
MySQLTuner.com  entire report.

Answer (score 0):

Considering these 2 posted lines of key_buffer information,
| Key_blocks_unused      | 857368 |
| Key_blocks_used        | 3      |

Suggestion for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section

```
key_buffer_size=1M  # from 1G which is USED very little.
```

and to get max_threads to a reasonable number, this is the variable name

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 2000 v5.7 5.1.5 CAP at 100
```

Answer (score -2):

Think I found the issue. Bad mistake in here.

As per following equation the configurations must change. As per the following equation needs more than 6TB RAM.

> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 6295169214 
>   K bytes

Think this will solve it.
Anyway after changing this, it should worked. But still didn't.

Comment: So, when will you post  current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used) Text results of: A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) complete current text of error log D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; E) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; Optional very helpful info, if available includes htop OR top for most active apps ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -x for a linux/unix for IOPS of hardware extended status MySQLTuner.com entire report,.
requested Feb 21 so we can provide meaningful assistance?

Comment: Added asked details on the question. Please look in to it as still I'm getting this signal 11 thing time to time with different errors

Comment: There has been an obvious thread spawn issue per the error.log.  If you could post (if not here, in pastebin.com)  current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used) Text results of: A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  I will try to assist.

Comment: Still need your my.cnf/ini posted and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  Thanks for the SGV.  Analysis will be delayed until posted.

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  if you can get one at 3 minutes, it would be very helpful.

Comment: What you mean by 3mintues

Comment: Reading your text, it looks like you system can quickly crash.  3 minutes may be all the time you have to hope to get SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  save the output with wordpad or similar software to be able to post it with pastebin.com storage for analysis.  We do know  your server has 64GB RAM.  Need posting for Linux ulimit -a results so we know your Linux Limits.  Still need iostat -x posted to know IOPS you are achieving at this time.  Thanks

Comment: and can you please explain this error : 

Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1bf531e8): DELETE FROM mysql.ndb_binlog_index WHERE File='./mysql-bin.001054'

This too comes with signal 11 sometimes

Comment: Please post your complete error.log where you are seeing this message.  Thanks for the ulimit and iostat reports.  If you would be willing to post SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; analysis of your system will be more likely to suggest changes to improve, until then we do not know WHAT is going on.

Comment: My apologies, I do see SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, posted first on Mar 13 at 12:29.  Will use the data to complete my analysis by Monday AM.  Global Variables followed on the same date. posted in pastebin.com.  Thanks

Comment: What is your typical client connection service duration from connect to disconnect/close of connection?  Could your provide from MySQL a General Log for twice this length of time?  I suspect we will see the 'connection' but no close of the connection for your client.  From my analysis, a short General Log will confirm this is your most significant problem, please post in pastebin.com.  Not releasing resources when a client's connection has finished their current session.  Do you have talent available to complete this task for your MySQL server?

Comment: Actually the thing is from my server program I'm creating connection pool which create 600 mysql connections. After that I'm using those connection to execute the SQL queries. Btw I configured max_connection as 800. the connections will close only if the server stops (program).